# Get Vimeo video duration with manual api call

Tags: javascript, json, iframe, vimeo, postmessage

I simply want to get the duration of a vimeo video. I don't want to use froogaloop.

The API states: "*You interact with the player by sending a serialized JSON object with postMessage() to the . The following format should be used: { "method": "methodName", "value": "value" } Omit the value key if the method requires no value."*"

I tried this bit of code:

```
*$wrapper.find('#parpap')[0].contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify('method', 'getDuration'));*
```

Firefox tells me: *NS_ERROR_XPC_NOT_ENOUGH_ARGS: Not enough arguments [nsIDOMWindow.postMessage]*

Chrome tells me: *Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': Invalid target origin '' in a call to 'postMessage'.*

Safari tells me: [*Error] SyntaxError: DOM Exception 12: An invalid or illegal string was specified. fixVideoSize*

Anyone got any advice? Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the errors is that JSON.stringify converts a single value to a json string (either string, number, object or array), you are instead passing to it two strings. What you should do is compose an object like this:

```
$wrapper.find('#parpap')[0].contentWindow.postMessage(
  JSON.stringify(
  {
    'method': 'getDuration'
  }
));
```

Know more about JSON.stringify on [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: Thanks, tried that, but still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you make a sample fiddle that we can play with?

Comment: Ah, now it works. I copy&pasted more stuff from some vimeo api examples. Haven't found out yet what caused the error and why it works now, but once I have I will post it here. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, for future explorers I think this is still missing an argument to postMessage().